# SQL query running very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to run a query in SQL Server 2008 and it's running very slowly when I change the value of one of the variables (`SourceID`). The below code works fine when the `SourceID` is set to another available ID but on the one in the code it just hangs... for hours if I let it!

The `email`, `dupe` and `MyMystery` columns are all indexed... any thoughts?

```
WITH rmdup as (
   SELECT act.Email 
        , act.FirstName
        , act.LastName
        , act.SourceID SID
        , ac.ID CID
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY act.Email ORDER BY  act.Email DESC,act.dateadded DESC) RN 
     from a_customer_test act 
    inner join 
          a_customer ac 
       on act.Email = ac.email 
      and act.sourceID = ac.sourceID
    where act.sourceID in (409) 
      and dupe = 0 
      and mymystrey = 0 
      and act.Email not in (select cemail as email 
                              from a_unsub 
                             union 
                            select email as email 
                              from a_unsubscribe)
)
select REPLACE(Email, ',', '.') as Email
     , FirstName
     , LastName
     , SID
     , CID 
  from rmdup
 where RN=1 
 ORDER BY 
       Email DESC
```

By the way, I can't run the "Display Estimated Execution Plan" as I don't have permissions and get the following error... story of my life!!

> Msg 262, Level 14, State 4, Line 1
>   SHOWPLAN permission denied in database

Comment: Can you list exactly what indicies you have on a_customer_test and a_customer_test? Also I'm sure it goes without saying you need that execution plan, even if you copy the db down to your dev box!

Comment: How many rows are in a_customer_test? Are there any indexes on SourceId?

Comment: hi Ian, SourceID is not indexed.

Comment: It's very difficult without seeing the plan but an index on both Email and SourceID on both tables may help

Comment: I don't know the size of a_unsubscribe and a_unsub, but you can use UNION ALL clause instead of UNION (UNION use more resources because it needs to find distinct values)

Comment: thanks guys, changed the union all. waiting for the DBA to update my permissions now so i can add the new indexes!

Comment: going back to how many records
a_customer_test has 5066293 (40082 have sourceID = 409)
a_customer has 135543207 (119020 have sourceID = 409)

as stated before, query run fine with other sourceID just not 409!

Comment: Can you show the table structure with Inexes included.

Comment: If you're partitioning by Email, is there any sense in ordering by it? `PARTITION BY act.Email ORDER BY  act.Email DESC`

Comment: could it be a cached plan issue that's has a bad join operator if you plugin s sourceID that produces 40K records in table1 and 119K in table 2?

Comment: a_customer_test is a subset of the records in a_customer, i created it to do some de-duplicating of email address. i use the "a_customer" table as i need the ID from that not the test table... yes i know its very "cut-n-shut" but the DBA wasn't happy about adding the "Dupe" and "mymystery" columns to the main table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect [statistics](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/when-update-statistics-flag-2371) for a_customer_test table are not up-to-date. Execute this in order to update them:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS a_customer_test;
```

Comment: sadly I don't have permissions for that either!

Comment: @user3157727: ask your DBA to execute this or create a clone of a_customer_test table (in this case you'll be the owner of that table) and re-run your query against your new table.

Answer (score 0):

I'll attempt an answer, in addition to the suggestion about updating the statistics I'd try adding an index to both a_customer_test a_customer which includes Email and SourceID.

I'd also check that indicies are in a resonable condition (fill factor and fragmentation).

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be to removed the where clause from the CTE and place it on the ON clause (Only do this with INNER JOINs not LEFT JOIN). 
The reason is when a Join is made, the conditions on the ON CLAUSE are made at the time of the join and eliminates a lot of the useless data while the data is being put on disk or in memory. When the conditions are on the WHERE Clause the conditions are eliminated AFTER all the data has been writing to disk or memory. The Where clause makes more work.

I would also change the NOT IN clause into another CTE and try to find a way to use something other then NOT IN. NOT IN is not as inclusive as IN. The comparison for NOT IN is not as natural to SQL as IN.

```
 WITH rmdup as (
    SELECT act.Email 
        , act.FirstName
        , act.LastName
        , act.SourceID SID
        , ac.ID CID
        , ROW_NUMBER() 
     OVER (PARTITION BY act.Email ORDER BY  act.Email DESC,act.dateadded  DESC) RN 
     from a_customer_test act 
    inner join 
          a_customer ac 
       on act.Email = ac.email 
      AND act.sourceID = ac.sourceID
      AND act.sourceID in (409) 
      and dupe = 0 
      and mymystrey = 0 
      and act.Email not in (select cemail as email 
                              from a_unsub 
                             union 
                            select email as email 
                              from a_unsubscribe)
    )
    select REPLACE(Email, ',', '.') as Email
     , FirstName
     , LastName
     , SID
     , CID 
     from rmdup
     where RN=1 
     ORDER BY 
       Email DESC
```